# For loop cannot find symbol i

Tags: java, symbols

I need your help quickly!
I have this small for loop and it says "Cannot find symbol i" or something, but I did defined it in the loop.

```
for(short i=0;i<pin.length;i++)
        if (pin[i].getName().equals(x))
            System.out.println("Όνομα"+"\t"+"Μήκος"+"\t"+"Πλάτος"+"\t"+"Εκτόπισμα"+"\t"+"Έτος Κατασκευής"+"\t"+"Μέγιστη Ταχύτητα"+"\t"+"Όνομα ιδιοκτήτη");
            System.out.println("name"+"\t"+pin[i].getLength()+"\t"+pin[i].getWidth()+"\t"+pin[i].getDisplacement()+"\t"+pin[i].getYear()+"\t"+pin[i].getSpeed()+"\t"+pin[i].getOwners_name());
}
```

Comment: Show us the code around that line.

Comment: Always put curly braces around your blocks, even if they've only got one statement in them. Failing to do so might lead you to strange bugs. Ask Apple how well that goes.

Comment: Thank you kwatford, I didn't notice there where two commands!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add `{}` to define your scopes

```
for(short i=0;i<pin.length;i++) {
    if (pin[i].getName().equals(x)) {
        System.out.println("Όνομα"+"\t"+"Μήκος"+"\t"+"Πλάτος"+"\t"+"Εκτόπισμα"+"\t"+"Έτος Κατασκευής"+"\t"+"Μέγιστη Ταχύτητα"+"\t"+"Όνομα ιδιοκτήτη");
        System.out.println("name"+"\t"+pin[i].getLength()+"\t"+pin[i].getWidth()+"\t"+pin[i].getDisplacement()+"\t"+pin[i].getYear()+"\t"+pin[i].getSpeed()+"\t"+pin[i].getOwners_name());
    }
}
```

Comment: Similar with the `if` statement...